# specs2 mock methods in a scala trait never verified

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, aws-lambda, specs2

I am trying to mock my interactions with an external API that checks a token to see if the user is authorized to perform certain actions (it is currently a seperate API as a PoC that is going to be moved into a middleware later on)

**DEPENDENCIES(SBT DSL)**

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "4.2.0" % Test,
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % "4.2.0" % Test
```

**TEST**

```
class MyHandlerSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
   def is = s2"""
     The first step is to check if the lambda is called on behalf of an 
     authenticated user. This is done by verifying that user token provided 
     as the Authorization header is valid by calling the auth API.

     Here, we can ${ConfirmThat().authLambdaWasCalled} by the handler
   """

 case class ConfirmThat() {
   def interactions = mock[Interactions]

  def authLambdaWasCalled = {
    val reqHandler = Request[Input](
       headers = Map[String, String](
          "Authorization" -> "Bearer gagagaga"
       )
      // millions of values that are not directly related
    )
    MyHandler.handler(reqHandler, null)
    there was one(interactions).authenticateUser(Some("gagagaga"))
  }
 }
}
```

**CODE**

The code uses a class MyHandler with extends the trait `Interactions`:

```
 trait Interactions extends MyServiceTrait with AuthServiceTrait {
    def authenticateUser(token: Option[String]): Future[Either[Errors, Boolean]] = {
  Future.successful(Right(true))
 }
}

class MyHandler extends Interactions with Utils {

  override def handler(request: Request[Input], c: Context): Response[Errors, Output] = { 
    //  get the auth token from the headers as an option, 
    //  there is a method in Utils that I unit tested
    //  it been omitted here for clarity

    val authFuture = authenticateUser(bearerToken)
  }  
}
```

**ERROR**

When I run the code, I see the following error:

```
The mock was not called as expected: 
[error]  Wanted but not invoked:
[error]  interactions.authenticateUser(
[error]      Some(gagagaga)
[error]  );
[error]  -> at com.lendi.lambda.MyHandlerSpec$ConfirmThat.$anonfun$authLambdaWasCalled$1(MyHandlerSpec.scala:71)
[error]  Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. (MyHandlerSpec.scala:71)
```

How can I ensure that I can either:

a) move the code for authentication into the MyHandler and do a partial mock for the MyHandler using Mockito provided by specs2

b) ensure that I mock the Interactions and inject interactions into the code so that it can be mocked correctly by the handler.

c) use a DI framework (should I use Spring for my lambda) to inject Interactions and mock it using the DI framework.

Comment: I am missing the code for `MyHandler.handler`. What does it do? Also nothing seems to actually call `interactions`. I suspect that you actually need to use `interactions` inside `MyHandler` by passing it as a constructor argument and not by extending a trait. And then you will be able to pass a mock which will be invoked during the test.

Comment: @Eric The `authenticateUser` is invoked inside the handler as an intermediary step. Apologise for the incomplete code, have fixed it up and changed certain messages.

Comment: The problem stays the same. You are calling `authenticateUser` from the trait that is mixed in with `MyHandler` and not from the mock object you build in `ConfirmThat`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your mock object to `MyHandler`

```
class MyHandler(interactions: Interactions) with Utils
```

and then

```
val interactions = mock[Interactions]
val myHandler = MyHandler(interactions)

MyHandler.handler(reqHandler, null)
```

Comment: thanks, will try it before accepting the answer, I have a bit of an issue that I cannot instantiate `MyHandler` and call the `handler` method myself. That needs to be executed by AWS as the lambda. Is this going to work in that scenario